# Lenovo z500 Intel HD 4000 + LG 35wn65c-b WQHD resolution 21:9

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have a graphic problem with my Lenovo Z500 notebook which has i7-3632QM with Intel HD 4000 + Nvidia Geforce GTX645M graphic cards.

I tried to connect LG 35WN65C-b WQHD monitor but the allowed resolution is 1920x1080 16:9 which is not fully filling my external monitor.

Do you know how to fix it and update it to 2560x1440 21:9?

Ps. On my Ubuntu OS the resolution is automatically updating to 2560x1440 21:9!

Comment: Make sure you are not cloning your laptop monitor, because then it will be limited to its resolution. Chose to either only have the external monitor working or to extend desktop. You can get easy access to the choice via the windows key + p. Either of those options should allow you to use the monitor at its native resolution.

Answer (score 0):

> On my Ubuntu OS the resolution is automatically updating to 2560x1440 21:9

I assume this is the same machine. I assume for the lower resolution you are talking about Windows.

Update the Windows Video driver and Chipset driver.  (Lenovo System Update)

Restart the machine and make sure the Laptop Resolution is 2560 x 1440. Check in the screen resolution settings that you have a full range of resolution settings.

Now try hooking up your monitor and testing. Make sure your monitor is capable of the higher resolution.

Comment: First of all the monitor is having enough resolution capability. I have another laptop and its resolution is 21:9 -- 2560x1440.

All the drivers updated to the latest version. I have added a special resolution level to my windows settings but at that time it is not presenting anything.

Comment: Did you do the Driver updates suggested?